# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found in extension

Tags: magento-1.9, database

we installed this : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-invoice-by-plumrocket-inc.html

we are facing error [here](http://www.appliedesign.co.nz/index.php/admin/)

```
    query was: DELETE FROM plumbase_product WHERE 
`date` < '2016-05-09 00:44:00
```

edit

```
core_translate`.`string`, `core_translate`.`translate` FROM `core_translate` WHERE (store_id IN (0 , :store_id)) AND (locale = :locale) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC
```

'
please help me to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given no background information/context and no code, my assumption would be:

- You've installed a custom made/third party Magento module
- This module is supposed to create the table `plumbase_product`
- The module would probably have a setup script to create this table
- You deployed the change
- You didn't clear your cache

Therefore, my best advice would be:

- **Clear your cache**
- Run all setup scripts

If you still experience this issue (your link is a valid Magento admin panel), I'd suggest you:

- Identify the setup script that creates the table
- Identify the version number of the module that that script corresponds to
- Check if there are any problem if subsequent setup scripts get run again, and if not:
- Reset your module's version number to the version *before the setup script that creates the table*, then repeat the suggested steps above

Comment: thanks a lot, i really needed your help now, let me clear cache.

Comment: once i delete the table, it gave as above error in question, i deleted table before you posted solution. cleared cache, no luck. what next to do ?

Comment: @user9999 why did you delete the table? To reinstate the table, find the setup script that creates it and make it run again (reset the module version number in `core_resource` - ensure first that subsequent setup scripts will not have a problem running again). All covered in the third section of this answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: how to `Run all setup scripts` again. please guide me.

Comment: i have table backup, i imported again, after that i got error in updated question.

Comment: now another error, please check updated question.

Comment: Your question now makes no sense. If you have a different question, please ask a new question.

Comment: please check and help me, i cant create one more question now as i dont have much  reputation.

Comment: Please come to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40866/private-chat-with-user9999

Comment: pls come to chat, agin problem started.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not related to the "auto invoice" module https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-invoice-by-plumrocket-inc.html
It does not even have the sql setup scripts in its package.

=== **UPDATE** ===

This table is required for `plumrocket_base` module which comes along with the installed "auto invoice" module. It checks for Magento version, list of installed Plumrocket modules, news feed, licenses, etc.
In order to reinstall it remove table `plumbase_product` and remove its line from `core_resource` table where `code="base_setup"`

Do not forget to flush cache after all.

Comment: @user9999 I have updated my reply